# Internal links to homepage: Should we point to root domain, or to our (required) final (redirected) homepage URL /home?

Tags: seo, technical-seo

Due to web app development constraints, we can't serve our marketing website homepage at `https://example.com`, but instead must redirect requests for `https://example.com` to `https://example.com/home`

I am seeking to know best practices for internal linking policy when linking to our own homepage (e.g. in navigation, logo link, etc):

*I.e., should we link to `https://example.com` or to `https://example.com/home`?*

Obviously when linking to `https://example.com` we are incurring more redirect signals during a Google crawl.... but don't want to necessarily deprecate `https://example.com` in favour of `https://example.com/foo` (I don't think anyway).

I'm struggling to know if there is a "right/best" answer here.

Comment: The best solution would be to change your home page to `https://example.com/` and redirect `https://example.com/home` to it.

Comment: Hi Stephen! Agreed - but this is not technically possible for the marketing team at this time. The development team is reserving control of https://example.com/ and requiring requests made to https://example.com/ to be redirected to e.g. https://example.com/home. I hope that makes sense (honestly I don't know the technical reason).

Comment: There are almost always ways to make the root URL into the home page. Rewrite rules are pretty much like magic for it. I'd push back on your technical team and get an understanding of the technical issue.

Comment: Yes, I am pushing back. It's actually for a client so there is a degree of separation here / diplomacy needed. Appreciate the sentiment!